# Installing SCM Manager (Mercurial admin web frontend) in windows

Tags: version-control, mercurial, iis-7.5, versioning, scmmanager

I successfully installed mercurial on Windows7 (IIS 7.5) and I got the default UI (default Mercurial admin web frontend). But there is no way to add repositories, users or setting permission through this UI. After some research I came to know about SCM Manager. But I am unable to install it. Can anyone please tell how to install SCM Manager on windows? If you can give the steps it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I installed SCM Manager successfully on Windows 7. I followed this tutorial http://www.helicontech.com/articles/hosting-git-svn-and-hg-mercurial-repositories-on-windows-with-iis/

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason why you use the IIS? You can alternatively use the stand alone version of the SCM-Manager that comes with a embedded Jetty server. Just unpack and run scm-server.bat.

https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/download